# @expo-google-fonts/inter could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules ..\..\..\..\node_modules

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was doing code in React Native:
[React Native Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjePD.png)

...when I stumped along with this error.

```
@expo-google-fonts/inter could not be found within the 
project or in these directories:
node_modules   
..\..\..\..\node_modules
```

I already had this package installed, but no matter how hard I tried, I still couldn't fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks!